# Conditional formatting - Stacked column chart PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

In the stacked column chart below, I was comparing the top line and the bottom line revenue. But for the bottom line value which is negative, I wanted to have a colour as red and value which are positive should be as green. While Topline will be always as positive so I can change that colour to blue as static. But for Bottom line Green for Positive and red for Negative. I checked in Data colours in the formatting Tab but conditional formatting option is not available.

Can you guide me on how I can do that?

[image]